# two tomcat servers using same port, rewrite rules for iis

Tags: tomcat, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, arr

I have been using ARR and rewrite rules to easily access my Tomcat application.

Like if the application is running at: `http://localhost:8090/alfresco`

After the rewrite rule it can be accessed on: `http://localhost/alfresco`

Here is an example of the rewrite rule I have been using that works perfect:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(alfresco.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http?)://" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:8090/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Now the problem I am facing is that I have another local server which has this same tomcat application name and port. Now I want to develop a rewrite rule so that when I visit: `http://localhost/alfresco1`

it should take me to that server which url is: `http://172.23.1.168:8090/alfresco`

Comment: Is there any reason why you use a back reference in the rewrite? My point being, is `alfresco` a constant in `http://localhost:8090/alfresco` and `http://172.23.1.168:8090/alfresco`?

Comment: that is the main problem you see the tomcat application running is named 'alfresco'. The rule i created above is matching url with the name 'alfresco'. so if i create another rule for '172.23.1.168' and write it in the rule instead of 'localhost', that would still take me to 'localhost' other than '172.23.1.168/alfresco'. cause they both have same url matcing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following configuration:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(alfresco)1/?(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http?)://" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://172.23.1.168:8090/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(alfresco)/?(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http?)://" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:8090/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

What it does:

- If the url starts with `alfresco1`, it rewrites it to `http://172.23.1.168:8090/alfresco/requested_path` using the `{R:1}` and `{R:2}` [back references](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules).
- If the url starts with `alfresco`, it rewrites it to `http://localhost:8090:8090/alfresco/requested_path` using the matched string [back reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules).

This configuration is based on [the fact](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rules_Evaluation) that:

> The rules are evaluated in the same order in which they are specified

The order the rules are defined in the configuration file is important.

Comment: thanks, but it seems that when i enter "alfresco1" it still resolves to just "alfresco" as the test pattern confirms also.

Comment: oh sorry ordering them works, first you have to write the "alfresco1" rule, it resolves to the correct path sometimes

Comment: @user1788171 Yes, sorry about this confusion. I have edited my answer and changed the pattern too to make the `/` optional.

Comment: when i enter "loclahost/alfresco1" it resolves to "localhost/alfresco" again cause the URL rule is accepting both "alfresco" and "alfresco1"

Comment: @user1788171 it doesn't trigger the first rule before?

Comment: i does but then the url changes into "localhost/alfresco" and it goes back to second rule.

Comment: @user1788171 Are you using `Rewrite` or `Redirect` in the action? Can you post your rules?

Comment: here are the rules, i am using rewrite:
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule44" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(alfresco)1/?(.*)" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http?)://" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://172.23.1.153:8090/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
    </rule>

Comment: <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule45" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(alfresco)/?(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http?)://" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:8090/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

Comment: @user1788171 if you are using `Rewrite` (and you are) there is no way the module will `Redirect` you. Are you sure you have nowhere a process redirecting your browser?

Comment: i have done this many times, write a rewrite rule in such a way that it redirects without changing it's URL. the problem i am facing is that both servers have same application name (in this case 'alfresco'). If i do this for different name, it works.

Comment: I understand but when you wrote `the url changes into "localhost/alfresco"`, what did you mean then?

Comment: for `the url changes into "localhost/alfresco"` i mean we have a rewrite rule which have this url to open application on my local server. The rule above it is `localhost/alfresco1` but when `localhost/alfresco1` is visited the application returns `alfresco` and the url changes into `localhost/alfresco`. I think all that is left to be done is not changing the url 'localhost/alfresco1' into `localhost/alfresco` and we are good to go.

Comment: This definitely shouldn't happen with the rule you have...were you testing with 301 redirect before and your browser cached them? Can you try with a different browser?

Comment: same thing with other browsers too i think i should look into `Rewrite Maps`, do you have any idea how that work?

Comment: I think it would be worth giving a try with the [Failed Request Tracing (FRT) tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules). It is easy to use and you will find where this situation happens. If it doesn't show up in the logs you will have, then this redirect happens somewhere else.

Comment: well, thanks for helping me out, your help is greatly appreciated.
I'll look into it.